# How to skip first n rows in U-SQL job?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to run a U-SQL job to load the data from .txt file in the SQL table on Azure Data Lake store. I already have created database, schema and table in Azure data lake analytics.

Data in txt file are tab-limited, and I need to skip 2 first row. I think that I should use `Extractors.Text()` built-in extractor, but how to add `skipFirstNRows` parameter in it to extract the data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass it to the extractor like this:

```
@searchlog =
 EXTRACT UserId          int,
         Start           DateTime,
         Region          string,
         Query           string,
         Duration        int?,
         Urls            string,
         ClickedUrls     string
 FROM "/Samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv"
 USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows: 2);
```

I based the example on the TSV extractor as that one defaults to a tab as the delimiter.

([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/extractors-tsv]))

Comment: I was trying with following: 
USING Extractors.Text('\t', skipFirstNRows = 2); 
Should use ".. skipFirstNRows : 2 "

Comment: Ah, understandable but optional parameter indeed use `:` instead of `=`